# SIMBL is implemented in two places on MacOSX

Tags: macos

I have encountered a problem when I launched mvim via terminal on MacOSX, the warning message is the following,

```
objc[679]: Class SIMBL is implemented in both /Users/username/Library/ScriptingAdditions/support.osax/Contents/MacOS/support and /Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax/Contents/MacOS/SIMBL. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I tried to remove one of files and launch mvim again, I still got the same problem. May I know how does it happen and how to solve it?

---

I am using Mac OSX 10.8.5